# Making a GET request with a secret that the browser can read, but the server can't

Tags: html, http, get, local-storage, shared-secret

Imagine 2 websites, both owned by me. On **website-y.com**, a user can click on a link:

```html
<a href=https://website-x.com/get_secret_token>Get your secret</a>
```

This takes him to **website-x.com**, where the server generates a secret token, and redirects the user back to **website-y.com**:

```
302 REDIRECT https://website-y.com?secret_token=foo
```

Now the server of **website-y.com** can read the `secret_token` param and do stuff.

But what if the secret token is also secret for **website-y.com**'s server?

The token should only be available in the browser, so a Javascript function can pick it up and do stuff.

I've checked out [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) as a solution that can only be read by the browser, but apparently I can't share data between different origins (so **website-x.com** can't store content for **website-y.com**).

Is there another way for me to transfer a secret from **website-x.com** to **website-y.com**, without sending it through **website-y.com**'s server?

Comment: You can put it into the "hash" part of the URL (`https://website-y.com/#secret`). The browser will not send this out with requests.

Comment: Note however, that if your get your page from website-y.com they could just put Javascript in that page to read the secret from you client-side. If you don't trust website-y.com, you probably should not trust their content either. (Okay, if you *own* both sites, that is not a concern).

Comment: Both websites are owned by me, I've updated my question with that information. I'm aware that I can put a malicious script in that transfers the secret to the server, but that's not something that needs to be taken into account in this case.

Comment: But putting the sensitive information in an anchor tag does seem lik a pretty good idea. However, won't even the web server (Nginx, etc.) pick up the full URL?

Comment: The hash is processed only on the client. It is not included in the HTTP request. So the web server will not see it.